# Recent Windows Update Messed Up Certain Keys

Tags: keyboard, windows-update, windows-11

After recently installing an update to my computer under Windows 11, I encountered a glitch where the ctrl, caps lock, tab, alt, and shift keys on the left side of my keyboard do not work as intended. When I press them, they only work for a second, and then stop working, so if I hold down shift and then "a" it looks like this AAAaaaaaa. This is also happening to my mouse, making it hard to drag and drop. It is not a hardware problem (I believe) because it also happens to my bluetooth mouse.

I tried uninstalling recent updates in windows update, but it will not let me uninstall any of my recent updates. I tried uninstalling them in the command line, and it said "update not found." My computer and drivers are fully up to date, and I have tried reinstalling the keyboard drivers. Please let me know what I should do to fix the bug!

Comment: See if your computer has a keyboard driver. It will have a mouse driver. Also try updating BIOS.

Comment: @John - They keys that are not working are traditionally standard keys on a 104 keyboard. Suspect something else is going on if the author is pressing a letter and it's shifting the caplization signal without user intervention. Does not sound like a driver to me.

Comment: If not driver then your operating system is seriously damaged.

Comment: 1. Check if any *accessibility* features are turned on, e.g., sticky keys: https://www.pcmag.com/news/windows-11-accessibility-features and https://www.onmsft.com/feature/windows-11-accessibility 2. Check if there is a third-party tool, e.g., AutoHotkey, doing this. 3. Use SFC and DISM t insure all system files are correct.  4. Check for malware (unikely).

Comment: So I've checked sticky keys etc. to see if they're on and none of them are. I tried turning them on and off and restarting, no luck. I don't have AutoHotkey so I don't think it's that, and I tried DISM and it says all of the files are fine. In terms of malware, I don't think it's malware because this glitch only comes up after performing Windows updates.

Comment: Try also [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html). (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: DISM did not work. SFC might but I have my doubts.  It might be easiest overall to reinstall Windows. Back up first

Comment: @John Is there a way to reinstall windows without losing application data?

Comment: You can try a Windows 11 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation link and Keep Everything.  If that works, it will not lose anything

Comment: @John I just did the repair install and the same glitch is happening... seems like it's an issue with the software?